# Is it legal to commercially use JProfile agent file (libjprofilerti.so) without license?

Tags: jprofiler

Without Jprofile license, i added the JProfile agent file **libjprofilerti.so** to my web application to enable remote profiling,  please let me know if my application is legal for commercial use.

The agent file is "**jprofiler_linux_9_2_1.tar.gz\jprofiler9\bin\linux-x64\libjprofilerti.so**".

I added and ONLY added the agent file(libjprofilerti.so) to my application and opened a port for remote profiling, so users can remote profiling my application with licensed JProfile GUI. 
Please let me know if my application is legal for commercial use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for legal advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed by the EULA. Source: I am the CEO of ej-technologies.

Comment: thank you very much, now i can add agent file to docker base image.

Comment: Execute me, before deploy i read the EULA again but still couldn't tell which section allow me to add only libjprofilerti.so to a commercial application, poor English. Could you help please?

Comment: "2. License to Distribute Redistributable Files"